# GetRuntimes Method in Microsoft Task Scheduler "Schedule.service"

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am working on code in VBA trying to determine when the next several scheduled tasks will run.  I am using the Task Scheduler COM object (`Schedule.Service`).  I can enumerate all the tasks, all their triggers, and even show the next run time by using the `NextRunTime` property.  What I am after is the next several runtimes.  Microsoft has the `GetRunTimes` method [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380759.aspx), which sounds like what I am after. But anytime I try to use the method I get the error that the object doesn't support the  property method.

I have tried in VBA, VBS, and PowerShell all with the same results.  I have tried on two Windows 7 PCs, Windows 2008 R2, and Windows 2012 and all have the same results.  On one Windows 7 PC the `Get-Member` shows that method, but gives the error "Cannot find an overload for GetRunTimes".  COM object browsers don't show the method either.

I have never encountered this before but I don't code all the time.  It is as if Microsoft documented it but left it out.  Has anyone successfully used the `GetRunTimes` method of the Task Scheduler object?

The error I get in VBA is

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

This happens as soon as it gets to the `GetRunTimes` line

Here is a portion of the code:

```
Set objTS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
objTS.Connect (strComputer)

Set rootFolder = objTS.GetFolder("\")
Set ColTasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)

If ColTasks.Count = 0 Then
    tmpArray(0) = ""
Else
    For Each task In ColTasks
        With task
            If .Name = "RebootSchedule" Then
                Set triggers = task.Definition.triggers
                'This next line generates the error, everything else works)
                Set runtimes = .GetRunTimes("8/1/2017", "9/1/2017")
                ...
```

Comment: please post the code that is failing and indicate in the code where it is failing (use a code remark)

Comment: Microsoft has [example code for C/C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446839.aspx), but it really does look like the method was omitted from the scripting API.